# can i replace a 15 amp transfer switch with a 30 amp transfer switch?

Tags: repair, electric

My motorhome came with a 15 amp transfer switch, i have 30 amp service, can i replace with a 30 amp transfer switch, as cannot find a 15 amp switch on  market?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica  Seeing it seems to do with 120/240 volts,https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ might just past it back.  Think we would be best to answer since it concerns building electrical type system question.

Comment: @crip659 That makes sense. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is no problem going with a higher rated transfer switch than the one supplied. Depending on how the connections are made, you might have to change some of the spade, eye connectors. You might also have to change the the mounting holes, mounting brackets but those are all fairly easy changes to make.

Comment: I agree going larger is not a issue but make sure it is known that a 30 amp RV service is normally a 120v,  50 amp is 240v  I have seen the effects in a RV that was connected to 240 was not good.